# Mix align and enumerate

Tags: align, enumerate

Is it possible to mix align* and enumerate, for example I want to TeX something like this (item a) and d), b) and e) and c) and f) should be aligned)

a) x^2 + y^2 = 1 b) a + b = c c) r-x = y+z

d) f - y = z  e) ... f) ...

For example:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{align*}
&\item x^2 + y^2 = 1 & &\item a + b = c & &\item r-x = y+z \\
&\item f - y = z & & \item ... & &\item ...
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A suggestion: Change your username to something more telling than "user4011".

Comment: An equation-per-line solution is given by the `subequations` environment from amsmath.

Comment: Related question: [force aligned equation all the way to the left](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27885/force-aligned-equation-all-the-way-to-the-left)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Aligning at the equation tags

`align*` is not required if you just wish to align the items. Here's an example using [multienum](http://ctan.org/pkg/multenum):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multienum}
\renewcommand{\regularlisti}{\setcounter{multienumi}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\labelenumi}%
  {\addtocounter{multienumi}{1}\alph{multienumi})}}
\begin{document}
\begin{multienumerate}
\mitemxxx{\(x^2 + y^2 = 1\)}{\(a + b = c\)}{\(r-x = y+z\)}
\mitemxxx{\(f - y = z\)}{\(a - b = 2d\)}{\(r+x = 2y-3z\)}
\end{multienumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Aligning relation symbols and equation tags

If you wish to align both at relation symbols and on equation numbers, I recommend to use the `alignat*` environment. Mark alignment points by &, further use & to separate columns. The argument to `alignat*` specifies the number of columns. Here we've got six columns: three for the tags and three for the equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{eqn}
\renewcommand*{\theeqn}{\alph{eqn})}
\newcommand{\num}{\refstepcounter{eqn}\text{\theeqn}\quad}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{6}
  \num&& x^2 + y^2 &= 1 \qquad& \num&& a + b &= c
          &  \num&& r-x &= y+z \\
  \num&\quad& f - y &= z      & \num&& a - b &= 2d
    \qquad&  \num&& r+x &= 2y-3z
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I used automatic numbering. You could do it manually as well, just take care of the font, the tags should be in text font. So they don't look like variables.

Comment: Please could show the variant with alignat* too? (align both relation symbols and equation numbers)?

Comment: @user4011: With pleasure, I added an `alignat*` version.

Comment: Thanks. However in your first example the distance between the numbering (a),b) etc) and the equations was better... Is possible to have additionally equal distances between numbering and equations for the alignat variant? (And how to control this distance)

Comment: @user4011: Change the `\quad` in the definition of `\num` to anything you like, perhaps just to `~`. I just used `\quad` to produce some space. Similarly, you can replace the `\qquad` by any horizontal spacing command, such as `\hspace{...}`.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a *tabular* environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}  

\newcounter{myc}
\newcommand*\mitem{\stepcounter{myc}\alph{myc})}

\begin{document} 

{
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{*{3}{>{\makebox[1em]{\hfill\mitem}\hspace{4pt}$}l<{$}}}
    x^2 + y^2 = 1 & a + b = c & r-x = y+z \\
    f - y = z &  a=b+c+f+g & t=s-r
\end{tabular}\par
}

\end{document}
```