# Alignment within enumerate

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate, columns

I'm looking for a way to sort of combine the features of `enumerate` (and other list-like environments) with features of tabular environments.

Specifically, what I like about `enumerate` is that it provides automatic numbering, and that it produces a straight "stream" of output that can be wrapped in a `multicols` environment so I can easily change how many columns I want.  What I need that's similar to `tabular`, though, is that I need to have multiple alignment points within each enumerate item.

What I ideally want to be able to do is this:

```
\begin{coolEnv}{lrc}{2} % specifying two columns
   \item This should & align & and stuff
   \item This should & also align & and everything
   \item This should & additionally align & and all
   \item This here should & be aligned & with the rest
\end{coolEnv}
```

The output I want is going to *look* like it's six columns, but it should really be two columns, each of which has three "sub-columns".  That is, my `{2}` in the environment is saying "I want two columns", but since each item of the environment has two align points, the separate parts should also be aligned as columns.  I'd like to be able to specify the alignment of the sub-columns as I have with `{lrc}` there, but this is the least important part.

The reason I want to do this is that I frequently find myself creating `tabular`s with some number of columns, but then later deciding I want them to be wider instead of tall and skinny, with the entire `tabular` wrapping into multiple columns (the way enumerate does in a `multicols` environment).  With `tabular`, this requires me to completely eviscerate the `tabular` and move all the `&`s and `\\`s around, because the `tabular` requires me to specify what is *shown* on the same line, not what data belong together.  I want a way to specify the *data* of the table in semantic "rows" (i.e., groups of info which must remain together) without having to specify how I want it to flow (i.e., how many such groups are printed on a line).  I want to retain the freedom to later say "I want X groups on a line" and not have to redo the whole thing.

I've looked at various combinations of packages like `multicol`, `enumerate`, `listliketab`, `multienum`, etc., but none of those seem to do what I want.  Is there a clean solution?

Comment: Does this possible duplicate answer your question? [Mix align and enumerate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12771).

Comment: That example doesn't quite do what I want, for a couple reasons.  First, it's using align, which puts everything into math mode.  Also, the numbering there goes across rather than down.  But the more major problem is that it's still making me type multiple semantic "rows" on one source row, which means having to redo everything if I decide to change the number of columns.  Like, it has `\num&& x^2 + y^2 &= 1 \qquad& \num&& a + b &= c &  \num&& r-x &= y+z \\`, but that is combining three semantically separate items into one row (terminated by \\).

Comment: @BrenBarn: You're right, your _question_ is quite different. I actually thought of the first part of the accepted _answer_ to that other question and its use of `multienumerate`. That looked quite good to me.

Comment: Well, my question isn't just about to get a certain output.  There are tons of ways to get the right output.  The problem is that most of them require me to specify information that's redundant, semantically irrelevant, or brittle with respect to later changes.  My goal is to get a certain output with clean, semantically-grounded input.

Comment: @BrenBarn Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21243/automatic-table-row-numbers/21245#21245) solve your problem?

Comment: Not completely.  That provides automatic row numbering, but it still produces a tabular, which won't wrap properly with multicol.

Answer (score 2):

I've always been using `\makebox` for this purpose. If it's needed more than two or three times, one could make a macro that accepts *n* arguments for *n* columns. E.g.

```
\newcommand\itemrow[3]{%
  \item\makebox[8em][l]{#1}%
    \makebox[8em][r]{#2}%
    \makebox[8em][c]{#3}%
}

\begin{enumerate}
   \itemrow{This should}{align}{and stuff}
   \itemrow{This should}{also align}{and everything}
   \itemrow{This should}{additionally align}{and all}
   \itemrow{This here should}{be aligned}{with the rest}
\end{enumerate}
```

But that is a rather inflexible solution of course.

Best