# Automatic table row numbers

Tags: tables, numbering

Is there any way to get automatic row numbers in table?

For example, if I define table contents as

```
\begin{tabular} % black magic column definition
   \rownumber & foo\\
   \rownumber & bar\\
   \rownumber & baz\\
\end{tabular}
```

and get something like

```
1 | foo
2 | bar
3 | baz
```

Comment: Duplicate question: [How to enumerate the rows of a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58138/how-to-enumerate-the-rows-of-a-table)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{\makebox[3em][r]{\rownumber\space}} | r}
  Something \\
  Other stuff \\
  MAGIC!
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

output

[image]
If you want to start with the  second row use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\def\rownumber{}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{\makebox[3em][r]{\rownumber\space}} | r}
  Something 
  \gdef\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}} \\
  Other stuff \\
  MAGIC!
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

output
[image]

If one wants a heading for the columns use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{\makebox[3em][r]{\rownumber\space}} | r}
\multicolumn{1}{@{\makebox[3em][r]{ID~}} | r}{\emph{whatever}}\\    
        Something \\
        Other stuff \\
        MAGIC!
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to start numbering at the second line? i.e. have a header row? TIA.

Comment: @Herbert Is it possible what Fabian asked? Starting at the second or third line?

Comment: edit the command `\rownumber that it test the value: `\ifnum\themagicrownumber>2\relax\arabic{magicrownumbers}\fi` then it puts only the number at the third row

Comment: @Herbert Do you mean replace 
\begin{tabular}{@{\makebox[3em][r]{\rownumber\space}} | r}

with
\begin{tabular}{@{\makebox[3em][r]{\ifnum\themagicrownumber>2\relax\arabic{magicrownumbers}\fi\space}} | r}

? When I do that, I get "Undefined control sequence" errors.

Comment: @FabianTamp: for the first (column in the first) line use `\multicolumn{1}{r}{stuff}` and it should not be numbered.

Comment: @FabianTamp just add `\addtocounter{magicrownumbers}{-1}`before the line of `\newcommand` this will start the number on second row.

Comment: @Herbert, can you please show more explicitly how to make numbering begin with the second row?  Perhaps an example with two columns also?

Comment: @littleO: see my edited answer

Comment: @Herbert How to do this for attendance sheet? see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409618/latex-tables-vertical-line-not-shown

Comment: Is it possible to add a header for the numbers as well? By header, I mean the first row --- in your example, 'Something'; I want something like 'ID' above the numbers.

Comment: sure, use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{ID}`

Comment: @Herbert thank you, but how exactly? Forgive my ignorance, but where do I put the multicolumn? I have a `tabularx` with columns like `id | col1 | col2`. So far, using the counter I had to put `\rowcount` in each row for the first column. I though I could improve this by removing the first column and using that `@{ ... }` thing (macro before each row??), but that way I won't be able to put the word `id` above the first column. Am I missing something?

Comment: see edited anwer (at the end)

Answer (score 43):

You could just make it use a counter...

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|r}
  \rownumber & Something \\
  \rownumber & Other stuff \\
  \rownumber & MAGIC!
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any frendly way to reset the counter between tables?

Comment: @miah: Load **etoolbox** and say `\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}`

Comment: @egreg I put that before my second table but the counter did not reset. I had to use simply \setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0} instead

Comment: @DavidDoria That code should go in the preamble.

Comment: @egreg Hm, even with that in the preamble, the row numbers do not reset for me unless I clear the counter manually as I explained.

Comment: @DavidDoria Did you add `\usepackage{etoolbox}` before doing `\preto`?

Comment: @egreg Yes I did.

Comment: @DavidDoria My experiment works. You can open a new question with a minimal example.

Comment: @egreg Ah, my mistake indeed. Again a MWE saves the day. I was using the tabu package instead of tabular in my real document, so I just changed the preto command to \preto\tabu and all is well. Thanks for the help and sorry for the confusion!

Comment: To clear the counter,
    \setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}
was enough for me too. 
I did not use
      \preto
or
     \usepackage{etoolbox}.

Comment: This works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 2):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has its own built-in counter for the rows called `iRow`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\arabic{iRow}}c|c}
&  Something \\
&  Other stuff \\
&  MAGIC!
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

A quick plain-format version as well for completenes:

```
\newcount\rowcount
\def\myhalign#1{\halign{\global\advance\rowcount by 1 \the\rowcount\quad##&#1}\rowcount=0}
% Yes, yes, next up in *sniping*: "One problem: you can't use repeating preamble"...
\myhalign{#\hfil\cr
  blah\cr
  foo\cr}
\halign{#\hfil\cr
  bar\cr
  baz\cr}
\myhalign{&#\hfil\cr
  asdf&asdf&asdf\cr
  sdfg&asdf&dfgh\cr}
\myhalign{#\hfil&&\hfil#\cr
  doesn't&work\cr
  boo&hoo\cr}
\bye
```

Comment: Two problems. 1. Every subsequent `\halign` will advance the counter even if it doesn't need it. 2. If a row shouldn't be numbered (a header), omitting `\the\rowcount` would not avoid stepping the counter. The stepping should go in the table preamble.

Comment: @egreg I wasn't aiming for a be-all-end-all solution; just an answer to the question.

Comment: @egreg: You don't need the `@<username>`-notation when you're addressing your comment to the answerer/questioner.