# adding row numbers to a pgfplotstable

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I've had a look at the attached answer [Automatic table row numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21243/automatic-table-row-numbers) but I'm not sure how to apply it to pgfplotstable. I'd like to get automatic rownumbers on my table so I can apply formatting by row index. (for subtotals and the like).

I have over 100 rows so its hard to scan visually and know the row number, and the columns aren't named so something like

```
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/new/.style={create col/set={\thisrow{columns={0}}}}}
```

followed by a

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={new,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}]\blah
```

doesnt work and gives me an error. Is there an easy way to get automatic row numbers in a pgfplotstable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the key `every first column` to display the counter value at the start of column 1:

[image]

### Notes:

- As you can see, I don't have much experience with `pgfplotstable`, hence the bad formatting. Will come back and fix the columns later.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{,pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{filecontents}
  \begin{filecontents*}{sample.csv}
    Column A, Column B, Column C
       99, 98, 96
       88, 87, 84
  \end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{sample.csv}\MySampleData

\newcounter{MyCount}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every first column/.style={column type/.add={>{\makebox[3em][l]{\arabic{MyCount}\stepcounter{MyCount}~}}}{} }
]\MySampleData

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks @PeterGrill. I had half hoped there would be something that used some of the pgfplotstable native functionality. Add a column before and fill using `\pgfplotstablerows` or something. But this does the job just as well.

Comment: @TahnoonPasha: There might well be. As I mentioned I have just started learning `pgfplotstable`, so perhaps a better answer will come along.  If I come across it I will post it here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the key `create col/expr accum`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/new/.style
  = {create col/expr accum={\pgfmathaccuma+1}{0}}}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
  3 7 2 7 8 1 6 3
  7 3 0 2 3 7 2 5
  1 6 3 7 4 9 7 2
  4 8 2 9 6 3 5 2
}\mytable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={new,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}]\mytable
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! You could simplify this a little bit by using the fact that the current row number is available in the `\pgfplotstablerow` macro, so you could say: `create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow+1}`