# Numbered list in rows in tables

Tags: tables, numbering

I want to have numbered listing in each row, I've tried with `\rownumber`, but it doesn't work. I wrote a number at the beginning, but Could it be automatically?  Can you help me? This is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{30mm}|> {\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{30mm}|}{\rowcolor{Gray}\textbf{Text}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|}{\textbf{Sem 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|}{\textbf{Sem 2}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|}{\textbf{Sem 3}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|}{\textbf{Sem 4}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|}{\textbf{Sem 5}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|}{\textbf{Sem 6}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|}{\textbf{Sem 7}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|}{\textbf{Sem 8}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|}{\textbf{Sem 9}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|}{\textbf{Sem 10}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|}{\textbf{Sem 11}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|}{\textbf{Sem 12}}\\
\hline
1. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text &&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
2. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text &&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
3. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text  &&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
4. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text &&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Automatic table row numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21243). If that solves your problem we can close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: @AlanMunn The solution that you referenced needs a separated column, I'd like to get as part of the text, like a title in sections. Is it possible?

Comment: @Isai, what does this have to do with the `enumitem` tag?

Comment: @Isai Herbert's solution doesn't require an extra column.

Comment: @AlanMunn Using `\newcounter`, the number fits in text better than `\rownumber`.

Comment: Your comment doesn't really make sense, since all solutions use `\newcounter` (which simply creates a new counter) but since you've solved your problem it's not worth pursuing, I think.

Comment: @AlanMunn Maybe I didn't reach the right code, but when I used `\rowcolor` in my solutions I realized that it is another column. But I find the GonzaloMedina solution works, not using `\rownumber`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppressed a row in your table which produces an error; `\rowcolor` is used in the wrong place in that row:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\newcounter{myrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{|>{\stepcounter{myrow}\raggedright\arraybackslash\themyrow.~}m{30mm}|> {\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5mm}|}
\hline
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text &&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text &&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text  &&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text &&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you're right, `\rowcolor` must be placed at the beginning of the row.

Comment: Nice answer! I was wondering how would you do have an output where in all the cells the "text" of the second line (and not row!) is aligned with the first "Text" in order to get the impression of an enumerate list?