# List across multiple rows of a table

Tags: tables, lists

Is it at all possible to create a table that contains a list that spans across multiple rows. That is the numbering must continue from row 1 to row 2 etc. My use case is that I have a table in a report that contain a single list of items. I wish to refer to these items in other parts of the report and I am constantly updating the table/list with new items.

The image below shows part of the table that I would like to create. Notice that the numbered items 21, 22 etc are in different cells of the table. When I insert an item between 21 and 22 I would like all the numbering to be updated.

[image: An example of what I am aiming for]

Comment: Could you provide a snapshot of what you want?

Comment: @azetina I added a snapshot of a table that I am aiming to create.

Comment: This may help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21243/automatic-table-row-numbers

Comment: Also this...maybe:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121553/numbered-list-in-rows-in-tables