# Enumerating Items within a Longtable w/ Section Numbers

Tags: tables, longtable, enumerate, enumitem

I am using `longtable` and `enumitem` and was hoping to enumerate items inside a longtable. I am making a template for RFQ and need to enumerate all points with the section/subsection number. I had a MWE example, which is shown below, and an example that does not work. I would like to use enumitem's label function to identify items while keeping consistent formatting (i.e., such as used in the rest of the document) which is why the MWE is not robust enough to be sufficient. I tried making a counter and then defining a label but it does not compile. I am open to other solutions. Thanks, all!

Here is where I got my idea:
[Automatic table row numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21243/automatic-table-row-numbers)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\thesection.\arabic*.}
\setenumerate[2]{label*=\arabic*.}

%% Counters
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{longtable}{| l | l|}

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Description}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{File Types}} \\ 
\hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Description}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{File Types}}\\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot

\thesection.\rownumber. Controls One-line & Visio or AutoCAD 2015 \\ %%<-- Works by has issues when text takes two lines
\begin{enumerate}[label = {\thesection.\rownumber.}] \item Mechanical Layout \end{enumerate} & AutoCAD 2015  \\ %%<----Doesn't work

\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `longtable` environments are centered already, so no need of using `\begin{center}...\end{center}`, but actually, I can't compile your 'MWE'

Answer (score 4):

A version with an automatic row counting and a specialized `enumerate` environment.

In my point of view, the `enumerate` environment does nothing healthy there.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{chngcntr}


\newlist{rownumbers}{enumerate}{2}

\setlist[rownumbers,1]{label=\thesection.\arabic*,resume}
\setlist[rownumbers,2]{label*=\arabic*}

% Counter is named rownumbersi !!!!
% Let it restart with the next table!
\counterwithin{rownumbersi}{table}

%% Counters

%\setenumerate[1]{label=\thesection.\arabic*.}
%\setenumerate[2]{label*=\arabic*.}
%\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
%\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{rownumbersi}\therownumbersi}

\newcolumntype{N}[1]{>{\raggedleft\rownumber}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{longtable}{|L{5cm} | L{2in}|}

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Description}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{File Types}} \\ 
\hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Description}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{File Types}}\\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot

%\thesection.\rownumber. Controls One-line & Visio or AutoCAD 2015 \\ %%<-- Works by has issues when text takes two lines
 \begin{rownumbers} 
 \item Mechanical Layout 
 \item Foo 
 \item Some stuff
 \end{rownumbers} & AutoCAD 2015  \tabularnewline %%<----Doesn't work

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was exactly as needed! Thank you soooo much!

Comment: @BryanManning: Alright, happy TeXing then! ;-)

Comment: I noticed a small problem, I want to assign one element of a row with another, thus, I would need only one item inside the \begin{rownumbers} ... \end{rownumbers}. What ends up happening is I get 1.1 for each value and using [resume] does not seem to help since each bullet point is at the same level. Could I amend the environment to take the row number instead of the sub-section number?

Comment: @BryanManning: That's changing the question ;-)

Comment: Would you like me to resubmit the question? I might've mistyped after a few hours of failure. :P

Comment: @BryanManning: I'll think about the issue, later on or tomorrow

Comment: Thanks kindly. I will play around with it, too, once I'm home! :D