# Nested numbering spanning through longtable

Tags: longtable, enumerate, itemize

I would like to find a way how to create such table design using longtable:

[image]

My plan fails on point when I actually cant find the right syntax of where to initializace/terminate the \longtable and \enumerate environments, so I am out of my league here completely.

Any help would be much appreciated, I already learned a lot here and hopefully would be able to transfer that information further :) Even pointing in right direction would be great.

Thanks in advance, Tomáš

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quite automated solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{etoolbox,array}
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenumi}{enumerate}{2}
  \setlist[tabenumi,1]{label={\themagicrownumbers.\arabic*},nosep,leftmargin=*,before=\vspace{-\baselineskip},after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
  \setlist[tabenumi,2]{label={\textbullet},nosep,leftmargin=*}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
  \setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet,nosep,leftmargin=*,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}


\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\mycolumnwidth}
\setlength{\mycolumnwidth}{\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth-2em}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|@{\makebox[2em][l]{\space\rownumber.}} |p{0.5\mycolumnwidth} |p{0.5\mycolumnwidth}|}
\hline
 Some prety long text including itemize 
  \begin{tabitemize}
   \item an item
   \item another item
  \end{tabitemize}
& Another long text that can contain linebreaks\\
\hline
 \begin{tabenumi}[series=test]
  \item  item
     \begin{tabenumi}
     \item item
     \item item
     \end{tabenumi}
   \item  item Additional text
     \begin{tabenumi}
     \item item
     \item item
     \end{tabenumi}
  \end{tabenumi}
& Additional text to 2.1 \vspace{2\baselineskip}\newline  Additional text to 2.2\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The row numbers in the table are generated automatically. The code for this is  [borrowed from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21245/134144) and slightly modified.

I have used the `enumitem` package in order to create two new enumerate- and itemize-like lists for the use in table cells. The first level of `tabenumi` behaves like an enumerate environment and automatically adds the rownumber (left column)  to its numbering scheme. The second level of `tabenumi` behaves like an itemize environment and uses a `\textbullet` insetad of a number.

The `tabitemize` environment is intended to use without a surrounding `tabenumi` environment as shown in the first row of the table.

Lastly, I have defined a new length in oder to calculate the column widths that are necessary to make the table as wide as the textwidth.

---

For a more open look of the table, you might also want to consider deleting all vertical lines and replace the `\hlines` by horizontal rules from the `booktabs` package. In the following example, I have marked all the lines with changes compared to the first example, with `%<----------`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{etoolbox,array}
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenumi}{enumerate}{2}
  \setlist[tabenumi,1]{label={\themagicrownumbers.\arabic*},nosep,leftmargin=*,before=\vspace{-\baselineskip},after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
  \setlist[tabenumi,2]{label={\textbullet},nosep,leftmargin=*}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
  \setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet,nosep,leftmargin=*,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}


\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\mycolumnwidth}
\setlength{\mycolumnwidth}{\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-2em} %<----------

\usepackage{booktabs} %<----------

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{\makebox[2em][l]{\space\rownumber.}} p{0.5\mycolumnwidth} p{0.5\mycolumnwidth}} %<----------
\toprule %<----------
 Some prety long text including itemize 
  \begin{tabitemize}
   \item an item
   \item another item
  \end{tabitemize}
& Another long text that can contain linebreaks\\
\midrule %<----------
 \begin{tabenumi}[series=test]
  \item  item
     \begin{tabenumi}
     \item item
     \item item
     \end{tabenumi}
   \item  item Additional text
     \begin{tabenumi}
     \item item
     \item item
     \end{tabenumi}
  \end{tabenumi}
& Additional text to 2.1 \vspace{2\baselineskip}\newline  Additional text to 2.2\\
\bottomrule %<----------
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I have to look into the package \enumitem to learn how to utilizate it, looks very usefull! Sadly I am now at work and cant analyze the code thoroughly, but its working perfectly!

I look into \booktabs for sure, at first the package documentation seemed a bit complicated to me, as being new to TeX :)

Comment: @TomášKruliš: You're welcome. I have edited my code to also contain an example using `booktabs`. If you have further questions regarding the examples or need explanation on how the code works, please feel free to ask.