# Long Table that Horizontal Line doesn't span some column

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am creating a table to record the sponsorship list regarding to the event hosting.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, left=2.4cm, right=1.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{cellspace,multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{1.75pt}    % <----
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{1.75pt} % <---- 

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}

\begin{document}
\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\section{Sponsorship List}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\normalsize     % <----
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C{0.7cm}|C{2cm}|C{4cm}|C{3.5cm}|C{2.5cm}|C{2.5cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}} 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{No.} & \multirow{2}{*}{Date} & \multirow{2}{*}{Company}              & \multirow{2}{*}{Manager} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Amount Secured}        & \multirow{2}{*}{Phone Number} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Person-in-charge} & \multirow{2}{*}{Status} \\ \cline{5-6} \cline{8-9}
& & & & Cash (RM) & Goods & & Name & Student ID & \\ \hline
1 & 13.05.2019 & XXXX XXX XXXXXXXX Sdn. Bhd. & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & Rejected \\ \hline
2 & 17.05.2019 & XXX TUITION CENTER & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & Rejected \\ \hline
3 & 17.05.2019 & XXX ESPORT & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & Rejected \\ \hline
4 & 20.05.2019 & XXXXX Park & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX& XXX0000000 & Rejected \\ \hline
5 & 21.05.2019 & XXXX TUITION CENTER & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & Rejected\\ \hline
6 & 23.05.2019 & XdXmy & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & Rejected \\ \hline
7 & 25.05.2019 & X\&X & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & Rejected\\ \hline
8 & 27.05.2019 & XX XXXXXX ELECTRICAL Sdn. Bhd. & & 200 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & Confirmed\\ \hline
9 & 27.05.2019 & XXXXXX NYONYA & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & Rejected\\ \hline
10 & 28.05.2019 & XXXX MARKETING Sdn. Bhd. & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & Rejected\\ \hline
11 & 30.05.2019 & XXXXXXX Coldstorage XXXXXXX Sdn. Bhd. & & - & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & No Response \\ \hline
12 & 06.06.2019 & XXXXXXXXX & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & No Response\\ \hline
13 & 13.06.2019 & - & WXXX TXXX TXXX & - & Dinner & +6 XXX XXX XXX & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & Confirmed\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Time Frame for Event}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}}
\end{document}
```

Because the table is too long for columns, so the complier complies the PDF as below:
[image]
The last column is missing and the horizontal line does not reach column 6- to 10. How could I adjust it so the table is in a page?

Comment: As it is, your table wouldn't even fit on A3 paper!  You can set columns to a smaller size, use a smaller font size, set `\tabcolsep` to a smaller value (by default, it is 6pt). Also you can print it in landscape orientation. Some columns could use the `c` specifier so they have  the minimal  width w.r.t.  their  contents – a typical example being the first two columns.

Comment: You may try tabulary instead of tabularx. Then use sensible margin and print the tabular sidewise on an A3 page which you enclose as exhibit to the report.

Comment: But I need to compile with other '.tex file..

Comment: What is your document class? paper format? font size?

Comment: @Bernard ```\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a smaller font size, a reduced `\tabcolsep` and the proper use of `X` type columns from the `tabularx` package you can easily fit the table into the margins. To make the table narrower, I have also introduced symbols for the "Status"  column. If your table will contain more entries it might not fit onto the page. In this case, you might want to use the `xltabular` package to allow for pagebreaks within the table. If you are interested in automating the numbers in the forst column (especially useful if you have to add a row inbetween) you might want to have a look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21245/134144

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, left=2.4cm, right=1.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{cellspace,multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{1.75pt}    % <----
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{1.75pt} % <---- 
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering}X}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{0.5pt}
\contournumber{10}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\textcolor{Green}{\ding{51}}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\textcolor{red}{\ding{55}}}
\newcommand{\nmark}{\textcolor{BurntOrange}{\contour{BurntOrange}{--}}}

\begin{document}
\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
\section{Sponsorship List}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\footnotesize \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}   
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|Y|Y|c|c|c|Y|c|c|} 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{No.} & \multirow{2}{*}{Date} & \multirow{2}{*}{Company}              & \multirow{2}{*}{Manager} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Amount Secured}        & \multirow{2}{*}{Phone Number} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Person-in-charge} & \multirow{2}{*}{Status} \\ \cline{5-6} \cline{8-9}
& & & & Cash (RM) & Goods & & Name & Student ID & \\ \hline
1 & 13.05.2019 & XXXX XXX XXXXXXXX Sdn. Bhd. & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & \xmark \\ \hline
2 & 17.05.2019 & XXX TUITION CENTER & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & \xmark \\ \hline
3 & 17.05.2019 & XXX ESPORT & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & \xmark \\ \hline
4 & 20.05.2019 & XXXXX Park & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX& XXX0000000 & \xmark \\ \hline
5 & 21.05.2019 & XXXX TUITION CENTER & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & \xmark \\ \hline
6 & 23.05.2019 & XdXmy & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & \xmark \\ \hline
7 & 25.05.2019 & X\&X & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & \xmark \\ \hline
8 & 27.05.2019 & XX XXXXXX ELECTRICAL Sdn. Bhd. & & 200 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & \cmark \\ \hline
9 & 27.05.2019 & XXXXXX NYONYA & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & \xmark \\ \hline
10 & 28.05.2019 & XXXX MARKETING Sdn. Bhd. & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & \xmark \\ \hline
11 & 30.05.2019 & XXXXXXX Coldstorage XXXXXXX Sdn. Bhd. & & - & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & \nmark \\ \hline
12 & 06.06.2019 & XXXXXXXXX & & 0 & - & & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & \nmark \\ \hline
13 & 13.06.2019 & - & WXXX TXXX TXXX & - & Dinner & +6 XXX XXX XXX & XX XXX XXX & XXX0000000 & \cmark \\ \hline
\multicolumn{10}{p{0.99\linewidth}}{\xmark~= Rejected, \nmark~= No Response, \cmark~= Confirmed}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Time Frame for Event}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to make the content in cells centering? ```\centering``` seem not working though.

Comment: @weilam06: The contents of the cells are already horizontally centered. Do you alos want to vertically center the contents?

Comment: Yes, so the table looks nice to me.

Comment: @weilam06: Add `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` to your preamble to alos vertically center the contents.

Comment: For the column that fill in the company name, how do I adjust the column width and height such that I can fill the table with whole page?

Comment: @weilam06: I am not sure if I understood your last request correctly, but the table is already is exactly as wide as the textwidth of the page. If this is not what you meant, could you please clarify what you mean with "fill the table with whole page"?