# How to write the same text in every cell in a table column?

Tags: tables, columns

I have to make a table, but with counted rows, except the head. It's okay to do it with a counter, but it's overboring write (or copypaste) into 144 rows. Is there any automatized solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\newcounter{lesson}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{@{}cp{{.1667\textwidth}*{2}{p{.3333\textwidth}}@{}}
Cnt&Something&Other something&Another something\\
\hline
\endhead
\stepcounter{lesson}\thelesson&Blah-blah&blablablablablablablabla&blabalblabla\\
\stepcounter{lesson}\thelesson&Lorem ipsum&ecc-pecc kimehecc&Abrak a Dabra\\
% and 142 more lines...
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Automatic table row numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21245/134144) (especially the second example) might be interesting.

Comment: Looks fine. What if I want to change the column specification for the head?

Comment: `collcell` allows you to do that.

Comment: Okay, but what is with it:

    \newcounter{lesson}[section]
    \newcommand\rowcount[1]{\stepcounter{#1}\arabic{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{N}{>{\collectcell\rowcount}c<{\endcollectcell}}

Says: no counter '' defined

Comment: @ThomasBenko with this setup you're forwarding the cell contents to `\stepcounter` and `\arabic`, so you'd have to always put the correct counter in that cell, I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Ok, that was my failure - a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the tokens to the column specifier.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}

\newcounter{lesson}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}{
  @{}
  >{\stepcounter{lesson}\thelesson}c
  p{.1667\textwidth}
  *{2}{p{.3333\textwidth}}
  @{}
}
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{Cnt} & Something & Other something & Another something \\
\hline
\endhead
& Blah-blah & blablablablablablablabla & blabalblabla \\
& Lorem ipsum & ecc-pecc kimehecc & Abrak a Dabra \\
& Lorem ipsum & ecc-pecc kimehecc & Abrak a Dabra \\
& Lorem ipsum & ecc-pecc kimehecc & Abrak a Dabra \\
& Lorem ipsum & ecc-pecc kimehecc & Abrak a Dabra \\
& Lorem ipsum & ecc-pecc kimehecc & Abrak a Dabra \\
& Lorem ipsum & ecc-pecc kimehecc & Abrak a Dabra \\
& Lorem ipsum & ecc-pecc kimehecc & Abrak a Dabra \\
& Lorem ipsum & ecc-pecc kimehecc & Abrak a Dabra \\
& Lorem ipsum & ecc-pecc kimehecc & Abrak a Dabra \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

You just need to use `\multicolumn{1}` to avoid the counter being increased and printed in the header row.

[image]