# Enumerate list with each item in a new row

Tags: tables, luatex, lists, enumerate, tabularx

Q: How can I create a table which contains a continuous numerating list with each item in a new row. So I can insert content for the other columns in that row.
I use luatex.
The result should look like this (Word):
[image: Picture of word table]
I tried it with enumerate and came up this idea which doesn´t work (look at the comments)(shortened content):

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper]{extarticle}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[left=1.2cm, right=1.2cm, top=0.0cm, bottom=0.0cm, headheight=37pt, includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{8cm}|X|X|X|X|X|}
    \textbf{Bezeichnung} & \textbf{Einzelpreis} & \textbf{Anzahl}
    & \textbf{Intervall} & \textbf{Rabatt} & \textbf{€/Monat}\\
    \hline%<----->
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*,noitemsep]
        \item System: Software as a Service  Geltungsbereich Arbeits- und
        Gesundheitsschutz % &40,00€ & 1&Laufzeit &10\% &36,00€ \\ <--- Idea but doesn´t work...
        \item IT-Service-Pack Release, Update, Support:\newline
        Übernahme der kompletten IT-Administration und weitere Dienstleistungen
        \item Management: Auswahl-, Bestellung-, Überwachungs- und
        \item Audit zur Evaluation und Qualitätssicherung %& 7,39€ & 1 & Laufzeit & 10\% & 6,46€ \\ <--- I need smth like this...
    \end{enumerate} &40,00€ & 1&Laufzeit &10\% &36,00€ \\ %<---- Only this works
    \hline%<----->
    Summe & & & & &36,46€ \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

which looks like this:
[image: Table created in Latex]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.
Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: And, what is the question, btw?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I edited the question and provided a working code snippet.

Comment: Do you mean different items should be in different table rows?

Comment: @Bernard as of my understanding, the `OP` wants all columns should be in top alignment, if not so, he may correct me ...

Comment: @MadyYuvi: I wondered, because the  last item in the Word screenshot is followed by non-empty cells, aligned with it.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I want to have a continuous numbered table with roman numerals. But that numerals should not be in a separate column. Therefore I tried that with a list

Comment: [Automatic table row numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21243/134144) might be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon [Bernard's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500605/134144) and the `magicrownumber` [from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21245/134144):

[image]

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[left=1.2cm, right=1.2cm, top=0.0cm, bottom=0.0cm, headheight=37pt, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\usepackage{makecell}
 \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\color{black}\bfseries}

\usepackage{array,etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\Roman{magicrownumbers}.}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\makebox[3em][r]{\rownumber\space}\compress}X|>{\color{red}}c|c|c|*{2}{>{\color{red}}c|}}
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Bezeichnung}} & \thead{Einzelpreis} & \textbf{Anzahl}
& \textbf{Intervall} & \thead{Rabatt} & \thead{€/Monat}\\
\hline
     System: Software as a Service Geltungsbereich Arbeits- und
    Gesundheitsschutz  &40,00€ & 1&Laufzeit &10\% &36,00€ \\ 
     IT-Service-Pack Release, Update, Support:\newline
    Übernahme der kompletten IT-Administration und weitere Dienstleistungen & & & & & \\
     Management: Auswahl-, Bestellung-, Überwachungs- und & & & & & \\
     Audit zur Evaluation und Qualitätssicherung & 7,39€ & 1 & Laufzeit & 10\% & 6,46€ \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Summe} & & & & &36,46€ 
\end{tabularx}
\vskip1cm



\end{document}
```

The counter `magicrownumber` is automatically reset at the start of a tabular, so in a new tabular environment, teh counter will start from `I` again. If you wish to reset the counter inside of a tabular environment you can use `\setcounter{magicrownumner}{0}` as shown in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[left=1.2cm, right=1.2cm, top=0.0cm, bottom=0.0cm, headheight=37pt, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\usepackage{makecell}
 \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\color{black}\bfseries}

\usepackage{array,etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\Roman{magicrownumbers}.}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\makebox[3em][r]{\rownumber\space}\compress}X|>{\color{red}}c|c|c|*{2}{>{\color{red}}c|}}
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Bezeichnung}} & \thead{Einzelpreis} & \textbf{Anzahl}
& \textbf{Intervall} & \thead{Rabatt} & \thead{€/Monat}\\
\hline
     System: Software as a Service Geltungsbereich Arbeits- und
    Gesundheitsschutz  &40,00€ & 1&Laufzeit &10\% &36,00€ \\ 
     IT-Service-Pack Release, Update, Support:\newline
    Übernahme der kompletten IT-Administration und weitere Dienstleistungen & & & & & \\
     Management: Auswahl-, Bestellung-, Überwachungs- und & & & & & \\
     Audit zur Evaluation und Qualitätssicherung & 7,39€ & 1 & Laufzeit & 10\% & 6,46€ \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Summe} & & & & &36,46€ 
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\makebox[3em][r]{\rownumber\space}\compress}X|>{\color{red}}c|c|c|*{2}{>{\color{red}}c|}}
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Bezeichnung}} & \thead{Einzelpreis} & \textbf{Anzahl}
& \textbf{Intervall} & \thead{Rabatt} & \thead{€/Monat}\\
\hline
     System: Software as a Service Geltungsbereich Arbeits- und
    Gesundheitsschutz  &40,00€ & 1&Laufzeit &10\% &36,00€ \\ 
     IT-Service-Pack Release, Update, Support:\newline
    Übernahme der kompletten IT-Administration und weitere Dienstleistungen & & & & & \\
     Management: Auswahl-, Bestellung-, Überwachungs- und & & & & & \\
     Audit zur Evaluation und Qualitätssicherung & 7,39€ & 1 & Laufzeit & 10\% & 6,46€ \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Summe} & & & & &36,46€ 
\end{tabularx}


\bigskip


\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\makebox[3em][r]{\rownumber\space}\compress}X|>{\color{red}}c|c|c|*{2}{>{\color{red}}c|}}
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Bezeichnung}} & \thead{Einzelpreis} & \textbf{Anzahl}
& \textbf{Intervall} & \thead{Rabatt} & \thead{€/Monat}\\
\hline
     System: Software as a Service Geltungsbereich Arbeits- und
    Gesundheitsschutz  &40,00€ & 1&Laufzeit &10\% &36,00€ \\ 
     IT-Service-Pack Release, Update, Support:\newline
    Übernahme der kompletten IT-Administration und weitere Dienstleistungen & & & & & \\
     Management: Auswahl-, Bestellung-, Überwachungs- und & & & & & \\
     Audit zur Evaluation und Qualitätssicherung & 7,39€ & 1 & Laufzeit & 10\% & 6,46€ \setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}\\ %<-------- Reset counter
\hline 
     System: Software as a Service Geltungsbereich Arbeits- und
    Gesundheitsschutz  &40,00€ & 1&Laufzeit &10\% &36,00€ \\ 
     IT-Service-Pack Release, Update, Support:\newline
    Übernahme der kompletten IT-Administration und weitere Dienstleistungen & & & & & \\
     Management: Auswahl-, Bestellung-, Überwachungs- und & & & & & \\
     Audit zur Evaluation und Qualitätssicherung & 7,39€ & 1 & Laufzeit & 10\% & 6,46€ \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Summe} & & & & &36,46€
z\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering :) This is the easiest solution that solved my problem.

Comment: I have another question... How can I break the enumeration? I have this table two times in my document and in each table should have I,II,III,IV...

Comment: @FelixB.: The counter is reset automatically if you use a new `tabular` or `tabularx` environment. If you want to reset the counter within the same environment, you can use `\setcounter{magicrownumner}{0}`. I have edited my anser to include a MWE that demonstrates both situations. I hope I have answered your question with that.

Answer (score 4):

I propose one of these two solutions:

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[left=1.2cm, right=1.2cm, top=0.0cm, bottom=0.0cm, headheight=37pt, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\usepackage{makecell}
 \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\color{black}\bfseries}
\usepackage{listliketab}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\compress}X|>{\color{red}}c|c|c|*{2}{>{\color{red}}c|}}
\textbf{Bezeichnung} & \thead{Einzelpreis} & \textbf{Anzahl}
& \textbf{Intervall} & \thead{Rabatt} & \thead{€/Monat}\\
\hline%<----->
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*. ,widest =VI, noitemsep, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, after =\vspace*{-\dimexpr\topsep + \partopsep}]
    \item System: Software as a Service Geltungsbereich Arbeits- und
    Gesundheitsschutz % &40,00€ & 1&Laufzeit &10\% &36,00€ \\ <--- Idea but doesn´t work...
    \item IT-Service-Pack Release, Update, Support:\newline
    Übernahme der kompletten IT-Administration und weitere Dienstleistungen
    \item Management: Auswahl-, Bestellung-, Überwachungs- und
    \item Audit zur Evaluation und Qualitätssicherung %& 7,39€ & 1 & Laufzeit & 10\% & 6,46€ \\ <--- I need smth like this...
\end{enumerate} &40,00€ & 1&Laufzeit &10\% &36,00€ \\ %<---- Only this works
\hline%<----->
Summe & & & & &36,46€ 
\end{tabularx}
\vskip1cm

\storestyleof{enumerate}
\begin{listliketab}
\newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\nextnum}{\addtocounter{tabenum}{1}\Roman{tabenum}.}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{LX|>{\color{red}}c|c|c|*{2}{>{\color{red}}c|}}
    \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Bezeichnung}} & \thead{Einzelpreis} & \textbf{Anzahl}
    & \textbf{Intervall} & \thead{Rabatt} & \thead{€/Monat}\\
    \hline\noalign{\vskip-1.8ex}%<----->
\nextnum & System: Software as a Service Geltungsbereich Arbeits- und
        Gesundheitsschutz &40,00€ & 1&Laufzeit &10\% &36,00€ \\[-3ex]
\nextnum & IT-Service-Pack Release, Update, Support:\newline
        Übernahme der kompletten IT-Administration und weitere Dienstleistungen & & & & & \\[-3ex]
\nextnum &Management: Auswahl-, Bestellung-, Überwachungs- und & & & & & \\[-3ex]
\nextnum & Audit zur Evaluation und Qualitätssicherung & 7,39€ & 1 & Laufzeit & 10\% & 6,46€ \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{Summe} & & & & &36,46€
\end{tabularx}
\end{listliketab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow...such a nice suggestion...

Comment: Thanks for answering :) @Bernard

Answer (score 4):

Similarly to @Bernard answer, but some details are different:

- for the first column is defined column type `E` for enumerated contents:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{E}[1]{ >{\compress\enumerate}p{#1}<{\endenumerate}}
```

which simplified writing lists in the first column

- for enumerate list is defined the following setup:

```
\setlist[enumerate]{%
                 resume=column,
                 nosep,
                 label=\Roman*.,
                 leftmargin=*,
                 after=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \partopsep}}
```

- for resuming enumeration of list is used option `resume=column`, in `enumerate` list set up
- for start enumeration at `I.` is dedicated `\setcounter{enumi}{0}` before first `\item` in column (see MWE below)
- I didn't bother with coloring numbers (it wasn't clear to me, if in some column all number are red, or they are select according to some other criteria)
- for compilation is used `xelatex` (due to use € characters for currency)

  Complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.2cm, vmargin=0.0cm, 
            headheight=37pt, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{E}[1]{ >{\compress\enumerate}p{#1}<{\endenumerate}}
\newcommand*\mcbf[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}l|}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\setlist[enumerate]{  label=\Roman*.,
                 nosep,
                 leftmargin=*,
                 after=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \partopsep}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ >{\RaggedRight}E{5cm}*{5}{|X}|}
\mcbf{Bezeichnung}    
    & \mcbf{Einzelpreis}    & \mcbf{Anzahl}   & \mcbf{Intervall} 
    & \mcbf{Rabatt}         & \mcbf{€/Monat}\\
    \hline%<----->
    \setcounter{enumi}{0}
\item   System: Software as a Service  Geltungsbereich Arbeits- und Gesundheitsschutz
    & 40,00€    & 1     & Laufzeit  & 10\%  & 36,00€    \\ 
\item   IT-Service-Pack Release, Update, Support: 
    
        Übernahme der kompletten IT-Administration und weitere Dienstleistungen
\item Management: Auswahl-, Bestellung-, Überwachungs- und
\item Audit zur Evaluation und Qualitätssicherung 
    & 7,39€     & 1     & Laufzeit  & 10\%  & 6,46€     \\ 
    \hline%<----->
\mcbf{Summe}
    &           &       &           &       & 36,46€    \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**addendum:**
initiated by conversation with @Bernard (in comments below) see if the following variation of mine original answer is more appropriate for you:

- definition of the enumerate style in tables is moved in preamble, where is now available to all lists in table
- for the first column is used `X` column type
- for columns with numbers are used `S` columns defined in the `siunitx` package
- your table is encapsulated in `table` floating environment.
- added are red colors for the second, fifth and six (last) column

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.2cm, vmargin=0.0cm,
            headheight=37pt, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}      % new 
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{% for enumerate list in "table" environments
\setlist[enumerate]{%      % moved in preamble 
                 resume=column,
                 nosep,
                 label=\Roman*.,
                 leftmargin=*,
                 after=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \partopsep}}
                            }
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{E}{ >{\compress\enumerate}X<{\endenumerate}}
\newcommand*\mcbf[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}l|}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
            >{\RaggedRight}E
            |S[table-format=2.2,color=red]<{\,\textcolor{red}{€}}
            |S[table-format=1.0]
            |l
            |S[table-format=2.0,color=red]<{\,\textcolor{red}{\%}}
            |S[table-format=2.2,color=red]<{\,\textcolor{red}{€}}|
                            }
\mcbf{Bezeichnung}
    & \mcbf{Einzelpreis}    & \mcbf{Anzahl}   & \mcbf{Intervall}
    & \mcbf{Rabatt}         & \mcbf{€/Monat}\\
    \hline
    \setcounter{enumi}{0}       % <--- reset counter enumi
\item   System: Software as a Service  Geltungsbereich Arbeits- und Gesundheitsschutz
    & 40,00     & 1     & Laufzeit  & 10            & 36,00 \cr % <---
    \setcounter{enumi}{1}
\item   IT-Service-Pack Release, Update, Support:

        Übernahme der kompletten IT-Administration und weitere Dienstleistungen
\item Management: Auswahl-, Bestellung-, Überwachungs- und
\item Audit zur Evaluation und Qualitätssicherung
    & 7,39      & 1     & Laufzeit  & 10            & 6,46 \cr % <---
    \hline%<----->
\mcbf{Sume}
    & \mcbf{}   &       &           & \mcbf{}       & 36,46 \cr % <---\
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Bernard, ups, there should be `\endenumereate`.  Corrected now.

Comment: If I may, I think the option `wide=0pt` is better in tables (spoils less horizontal space)? perhaps also you should create a new `tableenum` list, or something like that, to make the configuration purely local to lists inside tables?

Comment: @Bernard, it can be done as you suggest. Now the list settings is walit only for this table. If OP have more similar table, your suggestion is far better (I will wrote addendum with this). I first try to use `wide=0pt`, but to my opinion in  the result the items numbers are than less visible. As table is now, I rather use `X` column type for the first column, and S` columns for other except for clumn with head `Intervall`.

Comment: I also used `X`, but I must say  I didn't even think of the `S`  column type. That's an excellent idea!

Comment: Thanks for answering :) @Zarko