# How to add a table description to a longtable?

Tags: tables, description

I am very new to Latex and really need help. I am trying to format a longtable such that under the caption I can insert a description of the table.
I tried with \multicolumn, but then the first column got really long and the text didn't fit the page.
Does anyone have experience with this?
Thank you!

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{p{1cm}p{6cm}p{3.5cm}p{5cm}}
\caption{Overview bank sample \label{Overview sample compilation}}
\hline
\textbf{Rank} & \textbf{Bank name}  &   \textbf{Home country} &   \textbf{Local Index}\\
\hline

\endfirsthead
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{r}{Continuation of Table \ref{Overview sample compilation}}\\
\hline
\textbf{Rank} & \textbf{Bank name}  &   \textbf{Home country} &   \textbf{Local Index} \\
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\endfoot

\endlastfoot
1             & Allied Irish Banks                                                         & Ireland               & ISEQ20                   \\
2             & Banco Bilbao Vizcaya Argentina                                             & Spain                 & IBEX 35                  \\
3             & Banco Santander                                                            & Spain                 & IBEX 35                  \\
4             & Bank of America                                                            & United States         & S\&P 500                 \\
5             & Bank of Montreal                                                           & Canada                & S\&P TSX Composite Index \\
6             & Barclays                                                                   & United Kingdom        & FTSE 100                 \\
7             & BNP Paribas                                                                & France                & CAC 40                   \\
8             & Citigroup                                                                  & United States         & S\&P 500                 \\
9             & Commerzbank                                                                & Germany               & DAX 30                   \\
10            & Credit Suisse                                                              & Switzerland           & Swiss Market Index       \\
11            & Deutsche Bank                                                              & Germany               & DAX 30                   \\
12            & HSBC                                                                       & United Kingdom        & FTSE 100                 \\
13            & ING Groep                                                                  & Netherlands           & AEX                      \\
14            & JP Morgan Chase                                                            & United States         & S\&P 500                 \\
15            & KBC Groep                                                                  & Belgium               & BEL20                    \\
16            & Lehman Brothers                                                            & United States         & S\&P 500                 \\
17            & Merrill Lynch                                                              & United States         & S\&P 500                 \\
18            & Morgan Stanley                                                             & United States         & S\&P 500                 \\
19            & National City Corporation                                                  & United States         & S\&P 500                 \\
20            & PNC Financial Services                                                     & United States         & S\&P 500                 \\
21            & Royal Bank of Scotland                                                     & United Kingdom        & FTSE 100                 \\
22            & Societe Generale                                                           & France                & CAC 40                   \\
23            & SunTrust Bank                                                              & United States         & S\&P 500                 \\
24            & U.S. Bancorp                                                               & United States         & S\&P 500                 \\
25            & UBS                                                                        & Switzerland           & Swiss Market Index       \\
26            & UniCredit SPA                                                              & Italy                 & FTSE MIB                 \\
27            & Washington Mutual                                                          & United States         & S\&P 500                 \\
28            & Wells Fargo                                                                & United States         & S\&P 500                 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Source: Own depiction based on Bloomberg database.}
\hline
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. (See: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)). There are also at least two `\\ ` missing. One after the `\caption`, the other after the "Source" multicolumn.

Comment: Using `\multicolumn{4}{p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{<your descrition text>}\\` in combination with the `calc` package might give you the desired result.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you might be interested in using `booktabs`for horizontal lines with improved spacing. If you don't want to manually number the rows in your table, you might be interested in the following answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21245/134144

Answer (score 4):

I propose this layout, based on `threeparttablex`, which brings the functionalities of `threeparttable` to `longtable`, with a slightly different syntax. In particular, it lets you insert table notes anywhere you please in the table, so I decided to insert them just after the caption. I had to `\makecell`  here and there to make the table fit between margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttablex, caption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\providecommand\TPTLsourcename{\textit{Source}}
\let\source=\TPTLsourcename

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}[para, flushleft]
  \source: Own depiction based on Bloomberg database. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah.
\end{TableNotes}
\centering
\begin{longtable}{@{}c l l l@{}}
\caption{Overview bank sample \label{Overview sample compilation}}\\[-2ex]
\insertTableNotes \\
\addlinespace[2ex]
    \toprule
    \textbf{Rank} & \textbf{Bank name} & \textbf{Home country} & \textbf{Local Index}\\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{r}{Continuation of Table \ref{Overview sample compilation}}\\
\midrule
    \textbf{Rank} & \textbf{Bank name} & \textbf{Home country} & \textbf{Local Index} \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
    1 & Allied Irish Banks &
    Ireland & ISEQ20 \\
    2 & \makecell[tl]{Banco Bilbao Vizcaya\\ Argentina} &
    Spain & IBEX 35 \\
    3 & Banco Santander &
    Spain & IBEX 35 \\
    4 & Bank of America & United
    States & S\&P 500 \\
    5 & Bank of Montreal &
    Canada & \makecell[tl]{S\&P TSX \\ Composite Index} \\
    6 & Barclays & United
    Kingdom & FTSE 100 \\
    7 & BNP Paribas &
    France & CAC 40 \\
    8 & Citigroup & United
    States & S\&P 500 \\
    9 & Commerzbank &
    Germany & DAX 30 \\
    10 & Crédit Suisse &
    Switzerland & Swiss Market Index \\
    11 & Deutsche Bank &
    Germany & DAX 30 \\
    12 & HSBC & United
    Kingdom & FTSE 100 \\
    13 & ING Groep &
    Netherlands & AEX \\
    14 & JP Morgan Chase & United
    States & S\&P 500 \\
    15 & KBC Groep &
    Belgium & BEL20 \\
    16 & Lehman Brothers & United
    States & S\&P 500 \\
    17 & Merrill Lynch & United
    States & S\&P 500 \\
    18 & Morgan Stanley & United
    States & S\&P 500 \\
    19 & National City Corporation & United
    States & S\&P 500 \\
    20 & PNC Financial Services & United
    States & S\&P 500 \\
    21 & Royal Bank of Scotland & United
    Kingdom & FTSE 100 \\
    22 & Société Générale &
    France & CAC 40 \\
    23 & SunTrust Bank & United
    States & S\&P 500 \\
    24 & U.S. Bancorp & United
    States & S\&P 500 \\
    25 & UBS &
    Switzerland & Swiss Market Index \\
    26 & UniCredit SPA &
    Italy & FTSE MIB \\
    27 & Washington Mutual & United
    States & S\&P 500 \\
    28 & Wells Fargo & United
    States & S\&P 500 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c l l l}
\caption{Overview bank sample \label{Overview sample compilation}}\\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Rank} & \textbf{Bank name}  &   \textbf{Home country} &   \textbf{Local Index}\\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{r}{Continuation of Table \ref{Overview sample compilation}}\\
\midrule
    \textbf{Rank} & \textbf{Bank name}  &   \textbf{Home country} &   \textbf{Local Index} \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\endfoot
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Source: Own depiction based on Bloomberg database.}\\
\midrule
\endlastfoot
    1             & Allied Irish Banks                                                         & 
    Ireland               & ISEQ20                   \\
    2             & Banco Bilbao Vizcaya Argentina                                             & 
    Spain                 & IBEX 35                  \\
    3             & Banco Santander                                                            & 
    Spain                 & IBEX 35                  \\
    4             & Bank of America                                                            & United 
    States         & S\&P 500                 \\
    5             & Bank of Montreal                                                           & 
    Canada                & S\&P TSX Composite Index \\
    6             & Barclays                                                                   & United 
    Kingdom        & FTSE 100                 \\
    7             & BNP Paribas                                                                & 
    France                & CAC 40                   \\
    8             & Citigroup                                                                  & United 
    States         & S\&P 500                 \\
    9             & Commerzbank                                                                & 
    Germany               & DAX 30                   \\
    10            & Credit Suisse                                                              & 
    Switzerland           & Swiss Market Index       \\
    11            & Deutsche Bank                                                              & 
    Germany               & DAX 30                   \\
    12            & HSBC                                                                       & United 
    Kingdom        & FTSE 100                 \\
    13            & ING Groep                                                                  & 
    Netherlands           & AEX                      \\
    14            & JP Morgan Chase                                                            & United 
    States         & S\&P 500                 \\
    15            & KBC Groep                                                                  & 
    Belgium               & BEL20                    \\
    16            & Lehman Brothers                                                            & United 
    States         & S\&P 500                 \\
    17            & Merrill Lynch                                                              & United 
    States         & S\&P 500                 \\
    18            & Morgan Stanley                                                             & United 
    States         & S\&P 500                 \\
    19            & National City Corporation                                                  & United 
    States         & S\&P 500                 \\
    20            & PNC Financial Services                                                     & United 
    States         & S\&P 500                 \\
    21            & Royal Bank of Scotland                                                     & United 
    Kingdom        & FTSE 100                 \\
    22            & Societe Generale                                                           & 
    France                & CAC 40                   \\
    23            & SunTrust Bank                                                              & United 
    States         & S\&P 500                 \\
    24            & U.S. Bancorp                                                               & United 
    States         & S\&P 500                 \\
    25            & UBS                                                                        & 
    Switzerland           & Swiss Market Index       \\
    26            & UniCredit SPA                                                              & 
    Italy                 & FTSE MIB                 \\
    27            & Washington Mutual                                                          & United 
    States         & S\&P 500                 \\
    28            & Wells Fargo                                                                & United 
    States         & S\&P 500                 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if your description is too long for aline, use:

```
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}{%
     Source: Own depiction based on Bloomberg database. ... more text}}
```

And if your tabular is too wide, then use package `xltabular` and

```
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{c X l l}
 [...]
\multicolumn{4}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{Source: Own depiction based on Bloomberg database.}\\
```

Comment: Coud you please explain where exactly we can find the descriotion that the OP requested in their question: " such that under the caption I can insert a description of the table"?

Comment: Other than that, please note that the table is too wide for the textwidth of a standard `article` documentclass. You might want to add a comment on that, too.