# Auto-numbering lines of proof

Tags: lists, environments, enumerate

I have the following code to produce a Fitch-style proof (for use with MathJax).

```latex
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{A \to B \\ B \to C \\C \to D}{
    A \to B\\
    B \to C\\
    \fitch{A}{
        B \\
        C \\
    }\\
    A \to C
}\\
```

Is it possible to modify it in order to auto-number each line in this way ?

[image]

Are there any environments, macros or perhaps another approach I could take ?

Comment: Autonumbering *within* MathJax? I don't think it's possible. Does it even understand counters?

Comment: Thank you, @egreg. Do you think there is some other approach to accomplish this goal ?

Comment: As HTML supports counters I don't see why this is impossible. Whether or not this is possible probably depends how you are injecting this into HTML, which you don't specify. Related, from the TEX side: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21243/automatic-table-row-numbers

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, @Andrew. I am going to use it for posting in math.stackexchange.