# Suppress counter label in header of table with a custom counter

Tags: tables, environments, labels, counters

I created a custom environment to have the first column of a table be a counter with labels that can be referred to throughout the text. I can't figure out how to suppress the counter label (1) in the header column.
Here's what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{MWE of Issue}
\author{me}

\usepackage{tabularx}

% this is the custom counter
\newcounter{slots}
\newenvironment{planar}
{
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{>{(\refstepcounter{slots}\theslots)}rlll}
    \setcounter{slots}{0} %resetting counter after header
 Pos.    & Type  & Elements  & Forms \\
}
{
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some text here. 

% here's a table using the custom counter
\begin{planar} 
    \label{a}     & itemA          & aboutA & moreA \\
    \label{b}     & itemB          & aboutB & moreB \\
    \label{c}     & itemC          & aboutC & moreC \\
    \label{d}     & itemD          & aboutD & moreD \\
\end{planar}


% here are some references to the labels from the custom counter
Sometimes I want to reference something about itemC with a ref \ref{c}, but other times, I need to talk about itemA with a ref \ref{a} more.

\end{document}
```

And here is the output showing the additional label in the header row and the correct references from the labels:
[image: output]

How can I suppress this label in the header column, i.e. prevent it from showing up?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21245/134144 might be interesting.

Comment: thanks, I tried the solution mentioned there, but it either prints a (0) in the header (instead of the 1 I get now) or I don't see how to have labels there I can refer to later.

Comment: @SandraA. from the proposed duplicate the second approach in the accepted answer (with `\def\rownumber{}` in the preamble and `\begin{tabular}{>{\rownumber}rlll}
\gdef\rownumber{\refstepcounter{slots}(\theslots)}` in the table) seems to work ok for your document as well.

Comment: It does yes, thank you. For me, however, it only compiles without `\preto\tabular{\setcounter{slots}{0}}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the complete MWE that works, in case someone else is struggling with this issue. It's taken over from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21243/automatic-table-row-numbers/21245#21245) as mentioned in the comments, but for me it only compiled without the line in the preamble that resets the counter.
If you need a second table that starts over with the counting, what worked for me is defining a new counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{MWE of Issue}
\author{me}

\usepackage{tabularx}

% define the counter
\newcounter{slots}
\def\rownumber{}
% define counter for other table
\newcounter{slotsb}
\def\rownumberb{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some text here. 

% use the counter in a table with a header
\begin{tabular}{>{\rownumber}rlll} \gdef\rownumber{\refstepcounter{slots}(\theslots)}
    Pos.    & Type  & Elements  & Forms \\
    \label{a}     & itemA          & aboutA & moreA \\
    \label{b}     & itemB          & aboutB & moreB \\
    \label{c}     & itemC          & aboutC & moreC \\
    \label{d}     & itemD          & aboutD & moreD \\
\end{tabular}

% here are some references to the labels from the custom counter
Sometimes I want to reference something about itemC with a ref \ref{c}, but other times, I need to talk about itemA with a ref \ref{a} more.


% use the other counter in a new table with a header
\begin{tabular}{>{\rownumberb}rlll} \gdef\rownumberb{\refstepcounter{slotsb}(\theslotsb)}
    Pos.    & Type  & Elements  & Forms \\
    \label{d}     & itemD          & aboutD & moreD \\
    \label{e}     & itemE          & aboutE & moreE \\
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

And here's the output:
[image: mwe]