# Force aligned equation (all the way) to the left?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, align, enumerate

How do I force the following aligned output all the way to the upper left (right next to the enumerated list item)? I still want the 2nd and 3rd lines to be aligned with it's above equal sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item 
    \begin{align*}
      P(A \XOR B) &= P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)
      \\ &= 0.15 + 0.10 - 0.05
      \\ &= 0.20
    \end{align*}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related question: [mix align and enumerate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12771/mix-align-and-enumerate)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`align` is a display math environment; use the subsidiary `aligned` environment, instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item 
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
      P(A + B) &= P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)
      \\ &= 0.15 + 0.10 - 0.05
      \\ &= 0.20
    \end{aligned}$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Werner is correctly remarking the `[t]` that guarantees top alignment.

Comment: ...note the optional `[t]` to align `aligned` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

To use the `align` math environment (as well as the other equation environments of the `amsmath` package) but with the equations "shoved" all the way to the left, you should (i) load the `amsmath` package with the `fleqn` option and (ii) redefine the `\mathindent` length parameter to 0pt, as shown in the following MWE. (I've added a bit of "dummy text" to make the alignment operations a bit more easy to see.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate,lipsum}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\noindent\lipsum[2]
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item \lipsum[2]
    \begin{align*}
      P(A \cup B) &= P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)\\
                  &= 0.15 + 0.10 - 0.05 \\
                  &= 0.20
    \end{align*}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Hope this is what you're looking for. Happy TeXing!

Comment: I think the problem is when the `{align*}` is follows an `\item` without any preceding text.  This results in additional vertical space.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't quite sure if I'd understood the OP's question correctly. I thought he wanted to stick with the `align*` environment.