# I need help aligning my equations to the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

Here is my working code: I want my equation to be aligned to the left, does anyone see how?  I want each `\iff` sign to be under an `\iff` sign.

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
e^z &=& e^w  \\
\iff log(e^z) &=& log(e^w) \\
\iff ln|e^z| + i\cdot Arg(e^z) &=& ln|e^w| + i\cdot Arg(e^w) \\
\iff z + i2\pi n_1 &=& w + i2\pi n_2 \\
\iff z - w  &=&  i2\pi(n_2 - n_1) 
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27885/force-aligned-equation-all-the-way-to-the-left)?

Comment: @DJP: I don't think this is a duplicate, since the it seems the OP is after dual alignment: `\iff` flush left, with the rest of the equation aligned "as usual".

Answer (score 5):

You should [Avoid using `\eqnarray`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764), and rather use equation environments supplied by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). Here's one example that puts `\iff` flush with the left margin (using `flalign*`), while centering the rest of the equation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
  && e^z &= e^w & \\
  \iff && log(e^z) &= log(e^w) \\
  \iff && ln|e^z| + i\cdot Arg(e^z) &= ln|e^w| + i\cdot Arg(e^w) \phantom{\iff} \\
  \iff && z + i2\pi n_1 &= w + i2\pi n_2 \\
  \iff && z - w &= i2\pi(n_2 - n_1)
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

The use of `\phantom{\iff}` is meant to centre the longest part of the equation. `\phantom{<stuff>}` sets a box the width of `<stuff>` without actually typesetting anything.

The addition of [`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) is to highlight the text block boundary/margins, and is not needed in your final document.

For more information on AMS math environments (like `flalign` used above), consider reading Herbert's [`mathmode` document](http://ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode).

Comment: Thank you so much Werner! I want to learn more about LaTeX in the future