# Combine itemize/enumerate list and align environment

Tags: positioning, lists, align

I have 2 parts (i) and (ii) that I am trying to write out, but I can't seem to get the (i) and (ii) it look nicely, i.e. itemised. I tried using the `\begin{enumerate}` command but it doesnt seem to work together with the `align` environment? How would I get the 2 parts to be itemised/look nicely? (regarding the (i) and (ii)).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition} % definition numbers are dependent on theorem numbers

\begin{document}
\begin{defn}
Let $x, y$ be some unknowns, we let:

\begin{align*}
(i) x^2 + y^2 &:= (x+y)(x-y) \\
    &:= (1+2)(3+4) \\
    &:= (3\times 7) \\
    &\phantom{:}= 21 \\
    &\phantom{:}= 42/2\\ \\
(ii) x^2 + y^2 &:= (x+y)(x-y) \\
    &:= (1+2)(3+4)(3+4)(3+4)(3+4) \\
    &:= (3\times 7)(3\times 7)(3\times 7) \\
    &\phantom{:}= 123456789 \\
    &\phantom{:}= 42/2
\end{align*}

\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27885/force-aligned-equation-all-the-way-to-the-left

Answer (score 10):

Use `aligned` for this with `enumerate`.

Below I have used the `calc` package and extended the case to show how to handle the situation where the left hand sides are not of the same width and you still desire to align **all** of the `aligned` elements.  I have done this in two step just for readability, where you set `\WidestLHS` to be the widest left hand side in your entire list, and then apply the macro `\FormatLHS` to each of the left hand sides of the equations.

If all your left hand sides are of the same width, or you do not desire that the `:=` be aligned across the list items, then you do not need to use these two macros.

[image]

### Note:

- The math is still wrong in the question and has been corrected here.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,enumitem}%
% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{calc}%

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition} % definition numbers are dependent on theorem numbers

\begin{document}
\begin{defn}
Let $x, y$ be some unknowns, we let:

% Do this is two steps for readability
\newcommand*{\WidestLHS}{x^2 +2xy + y^2}%
\newcommand*{\FormatLHS}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{$\WidestLHS$}][r]{$#1$}}%
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\roman*)}]
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
\FormatLHS{x^2 - y^2} &:= (x+y)(x-y) \\
    &:= (1+2)(3+4) \\
    &:= (3\times 7) \\
    &\phantom{:}= 21 \\
    &\phantom{:}= 42/2
\end{aligned}$
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
\FormatLHS{x^2 - y^2} &:= (x+y)(x-y) \\
    &:= (1+2)(3+4)(3+4)(3+4)(3+4) \\
    &:= (3\times 7)(3\times 7)(3\times 7) \\
    &\phantom{:}= 123456789 \\
    &\phantom{:}= 42/2
\end{aligned}$
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
\FormatLHS{x^2 +2xy + y^2} &:= (x+y)^2
\end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{defn}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, need to study thosenew commands because I have not seen them before. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an option with left-aligned equation numbers (by passing the `leqno` option to [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s or the document class):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{amsthm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition} % definition numbers are dependent on theorem numbers

\begin{document}
\begin{defn}
Let $x, y$ be some unknowns, we let:

\begin{align*}
x^2 - y^2 &:= (x+y)(x-y) \tag{\textit{i}} \label{eq:first} \\
    &:= (1+2)(3+4) \\
    &:= (5\times 6) \\
    &\phantom{:}= 30 \\
    &\phantom{:}= 60/2 \\ \\
x^2 - y^2 &:= (x+y)(x-y) \tag{\textit{ii}} \label{eq:second} \\
    &:= (1+2)(3+4)(5+6)(7+8)(9+0) \\
    &:= (1\times 2)(3\times 4)(5\times 6) \\
    &\phantom{:}= 123456789 \\
    &\phantom{:}= 42/2
\end{align*}
It is obvious that the mathematics in~\eqref{eq:first} and~\eqref{eq:second} is incorrect.
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

`\tag` can be used to override the regular numbering and/or formatting.

Note that this will affect your equation numbering globally.

Comment: Thanks Werner! Interesting way to do it with the equation numbering, going to explore further into that.

Comment: You can simplify ii to -1 :^)