# List label and equation on the same line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align, lists

I'm doing my (high school) math homework using LaTeX. As you might expect, I primarily use nested lists and multiline "Solve for *x*"-type equations. 
 The `align` environment and its other non`-ed` ending brethren do not allow vertical alignment of the list label with the first line of the equation (as you would get using `\item \(\begin{aligned}[t]...`, say).

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Here is a list containing two unimaginative equations:

\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
        \begin{align*}
            x^2 - 2x - 8 &= x^2 - 4x + 2x - 8\\
            &= (x-4)(x+2)
        \end{align*}

    \item
        \(\begin{aligned}[t]
            x^2 - 2x - 8 &= x^2 - 4x + 2x - 8\\
            &= (x-4)(x+2)
        \end{aligned}\)
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the `aligned` environment (a) gives an uncentered equation and (b) deprives me of equation numbering privileges (though I would still like to know how to centre these; using \centering doesn't work, neither does inserting two `\hfill`s on either side of `\(...\)`).

An `align` or `IEEEeqnarray` environment that allows space for the list label would be ideal. I do not like the solution of aligning the equation numbers on the left, as some list items would contain text as well.

Comment: What about `\item\hfil\(\begin{aligned}[t] x^2...`?

Comment: Using left aligned equation numbers instead of the itemize numbers as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46648/134144 could also be interesting.

Comment: @leandriis I rarely use equation referencing while solving questions, so I can now improve the look of about 90% of my homework. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two solutions, including one for numbered equations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Here is a list containing two unimaginative equations:

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr\abovedisplayskip + \baselineskip}\begin{align}
            x^2 - 2x - 8 &= x^2 - 4x + 2x - 8\\
            &= (x-4)(x+2)
        \end{align}

    \item \makebox[\linewidth]{\(\begin{aligned}[t]
            x^2 - 2x - 8 &= x^2 - 4x + 2x - 8\\
            &= (x-4)(x+2)
        \end{aligned}\)}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you!