# enumerate in multicols

Tags: lists, multicol, enumitem

The following image illustrates what am looking for:

[image]

Essentially I want the numbering to occur as shown above but using the `multicol` and `enumitem` package. But when I try it by using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem,multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Evaluate each of the following if $x$ is a non-zero real number.
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=1cm]% The item sep is my choice here.
    \item $\dfrac{|x|}{x}$
    \item $\dfrac{x}{|x|}$
    \item $\dfrac{|-x|}{-x}$
    \item $|x|-|-x|$
    \end{enumerate} 
    \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

Essentially, I want the `(b)` to be where the `(c)` is. I know this has been done but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: +1 An ugly way round it- use two sets of `multicols` and `resume` the `enumerate`, but hopefully someone has a more elegant way

Comment: @cmhughes yeah ugly indeed :-)

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51520/automatic-line-break-in-alignat/51543#51543

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Nice, I agree it is similar to my question but am not looking for a `mathmode` environment rather some listing method such as the `enumitem` package along with the `multicol` package.

Comment: Not sure why you pre-determine the needed packages, rather than just the outcome, but whatever. Your example text was a sequence of math displays each labelled with a counter, which is same as the other question. multicol reading order is _down_ the columns, if you want a reading order that is across the page, you don't want multicol. Or you want to disable all its features which is harder.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand what you are saying. Thumbs up on your response but am just checking if it is possible, else I will definitely use your code. It is definitely not fixed, my choice of packages but the use of the multicol package can automatically fix more columns and the enumitem the separation of the items and much more. Just saying. :-)

Comment: The number of columns and separation is trivial, if you don't need the additional alignment points as in the other answer it's even easier, I'll put some code in an answer:-)

Comment: The [`tasks`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tasks) package was designed for this purpose

Comment: @cgnieder Add it as a solution. It does do what you say. Thanks for the update on that package.

Comment: Similar question for `parts` and `subparts` in the LaTeX `exam` class: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597536/exam-parts-in-multicols-left-to-right-numbering

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an option using the defined `\newitem` command. The contents is set in a `\parbox` that naturally flows left-to-right, providing the enumeration in the style you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem,multicol,setspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{enumitem,multicol,setspace}
\newcounter{subenum}[enumi]
\renewcommand{\thesubenum}{\alph{subenum}}
\newcommand{\newitem}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subenum}%
  \parbox{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-.5\columnsep}{%
    \makebox[\labelwidth][r]{(\thesubenum)\hspace*{\labelsep}}%
    #1}\hfill%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[start=8]
  \item Evaluate each of the following if $x$ is a non-zero real number.
    \begin{multicols}{2}
      \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=1cm]% The item sep is my choice here.
        \item $\dfrac{|x|}{x}$
        \item $\dfrac{x}{|x|}$
        \item $\dfrac{|-x|}{-x}$
        \item $|x|-|-x|$
      \end{enumerate} 
    \end{multicols}
  \item Evaluate each of the following if $x$ is a non-zero real number.\par
    \setstretch{3}%
    \newitem{$\dfrac{|x|}{x}$}
    \newitem{$\dfrac{x}{|x|}$}
    \newitem{$\dfrac{|-x|}{-x}$}
    \newitem{$|x|-|-x|$}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Spacing consideration is provided by [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) and can be tweaked (also removing some additional "`\topsep`" white space, if needed).

---

For a slightly more automated approach to changing the number of columns, add

```
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
```

to your document preamble, and use

```
\FPeval\thecolwidth{round(1/4:4)}% Specify number of columns -> column width
\newcommand{\newitem}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{subenum}%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\thecolwidth\linewidth-.5\columnsep}{%
    \makebox[\labelwidth][r]{(\thesubenum)\hspace*{\labelsep}}%
    #1}\hfill%
}
```

as your definition for `\newitem`. Modify `1/4` to `1/<col nums>` to increase the number of columns.

Comment: What if I wanted three columns? Or maybe 4 columns? Do I need to edit `\dimexpr.5\linewidth-.5\columnsep`?

Comment: @azetina: Correct. For 3 columns, you could use `\dimexpr.3333\linewidth-.5\columnsep`, while 4 columns could use `\dimexpr.25\linewidth-.5\columnsep`.

Comment: Can one make the calculations like `\def\newnum\dimexpr 1/#1 \relax`? or something like that to avoid the decimals?

Comment: @azetina: I've added some calculations to the post, referencing the [`fp` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) for convenient calculations of the column widths.

Comment: Hi @Werner, would it be possible to adapt this answer for `parts` and `subparts` in the `exam` class? Thank you in advance.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597536/exam-parts-in-multicols-left-to-right-numbering

Answer (score 9):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\tracingall
\def\horizlist#1#2#3{%
  \setcounter{enumi}{0}%
  #3%
  \flushleft
  \dimen0 \linewidth
  \divide\dimen0 by #1\relax
  \advance\dimen0 -#2\relax
  \def\item{\hfil\egroup\penalty50 \hfill
  \refstepcounter{enumi}%
  \leavevmode\hbox to \dimen0 \bgroup\space(\theenumi)\space}%
  \leavevmode\bgroup\hskip 0pt plus -1fill }

\def\endhorizlist{\hfil\egroup\endflushleft}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Evaluate each of the following if $x$ is a non-zero real number.
    \begin{horizlist}{2}{1cm}{\renewcommand\theenumi{\alph{enumi}}}
    \item $\dfrac{|x|}{x}$
    \item $\dfrac{x}{|x|}$
    \item $\dfrac{|-x|}{-x}$
    \item $|x|-|-x|$
    \end{horizlist}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

---

To see what is happening here, if you want the numbering to go right-left before down that is normal paragraph word order so the thing to do is just make a series of boxes of fixed width If they are (say) 1/3 of text width and you makes a paragraph of such boxes in a flush left paragraph then Tex will naturally wrap the paragraph with three boxes on a line and they will align vertically as they are all the same width. the rest of the code just increments a counter and puts (\the...) at the front of the box, and hides the `\makebox[0.3\textwidth]{...}` syntax to use the standard `\item` syntax so it is easy to switch between list types.

In other words compare to the following which is the same apart from cosmetic syntax changes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}

\makebox[.3\textwidth][l]{one one}
\makebox[.3\textwidth][l]{two 2 two 2 two}
\makebox[.3\textwidth][l]{three three 3}
\makebox[.3\textwidth][l]{4 4 4 4 4 }
\makebox[.3\textwidth][l]{fifth box}
\makebox[.3\textwidth][l]{number 6}
\makebox[.3\textwidth][l]{7 7 7 7 }
\makebox[.3\textwidth][l]{eight}
\makebox[.3\textwidth][l]{nine nine}
\makebox[.3\textwidth][l]{10}

\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Even though the result has the appearance of being in three columns, it is just a typeset paragraph with the alignment being automatic as each "word" in the paragraph is a box of equal size.

Answer (score 7):

This is easy with the [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) package and the [`tasks`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tasks) package. The following example hopefully is self-explaining:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\usepackage{exsheets}% loads the `tasks' package
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = runin-nr
}
\settasks{
  counter-format = tsk[a]. ,
  label-format = \sffamily\itshape\bfseries
}

\setcounter{question}{43}% only for this example

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  Evaluate each of the following if $x$ is a non-zero real number.
  \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $\dfrac{\abs{x}}{x}$
    \task $\dfrac{x}{\abs{x}}$
    \task $\dfrac{\abs{-x}}{-x}$
    \task $\abs{x}-\abs{-x}$
  \end{tasks}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is another solution which does not have to define a new `\item` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}%for \dfrac
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}%for enviroment enumerate*
\usepackage{tabto}%for \tab and \NumTabs
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[start=44]
\item Evaluate each of the following if $x$ is a non-zero real number.\\
  \NumTabs{2}
  \begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin=\tab]
  \item $\dfrac{|x|}{x}$
  \item $\dfrac{x}{|x|}$
  \item $\dfrac{|-x|}{-x}$
  \item $|x|-|-x|$
  \end{enumerate*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here is what the solution looks like
[image: Multi Column Text]

The command `\NumTabs{2}` is a to specify that there should be two tab stops, 
this uses the *current* value of `\linewidth` 
to create tab stops for the *rest* of the document.
Thus if the line width changes and if you need to use tabs, 
then it is best to rewrite `\NumTabs{2}`.
The command `\tab` makes the text that follows it to be positioned at the next tab stop.

The environment `enumerate*` is used to create inline lists, 
thus I put a `\\` after "is a non-zero real number."
The option `itemjoin` is used to specify what comes between the items,
in this case the command `\tab` comes in between each item.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a boring one that uses the `resume` functionality of [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) package. It's not the most efficient as the code starts stops the `enumerate` environment too much. But the result is acceptable visually. You can introduce all kinds of additional tweaks since it's just a tabular environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\Choices}[4]{\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth} p{0.5\textwidth}} 
\begin{enumerate*}[series=lafter]
    \item #1
\end{enumerate*} &%
\begin{enumerate*}[resume=lafter]
    \item #2
\end{enumerate*} \\[2\baselineskip]
\begin{enumerate*}[resume=lafter]
    \item #3
\end{enumerate*} &%
\begin{enumerate*}[resume=lafter]
    \item #4
\end{enumerate*}
\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Evaluate each of the following if $x$ is a non-zero real number.

\Choices{$\dfrac{|x|}{x}$}{$\dfrac{x}{|x|}$}{$\dfrac{|-x|}{-x}$}{$|x|-|-x|$}

\item Evaluate each of the following if you can.

\Choices{This question is not answerable (is that a real word?)}
{This question does not have any correct answer}
{$\int_0^\pi{\tan\sqrt\theta d\theta}$}
{Whatever is a valid answer!}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this is limited to the number of inputs possible; like in your case we are looking at four options only. Say I wanted 3 columns and 12 such problems, what will I do then? Surely I can edit your code and input the amount I want but I guess its a bit cumbersome :-) Nice way. Learnt about `lafter`.

Comment: @azetina Note that, it only solves the given problem :) You can make it flexible by allocating rows and numbers first and supplying an array of answers, if you wish. By the way `lafter` is just the name of the list, you are free to choose anything.

Comment: Yah I know, I actually meant the `series` idea.