# multicols without empty space

Tags: enumerate

What code does the following generate for me?
[image]

I Try this:

```
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item $5\in A$
\item $10\in A$
\item $3\in B$
\item $16\in B$
\item $9\in C$
\item $35\over 2\in C\cap D$
\item $35\in D$
\item $7\in (B\cap D)\cup A$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
```

but this code generates
[image]

Comment: For such task is intended `tasks` package: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task A
\task B
\task C
\task D
\task E
\task F
\task G
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task A
\task B
\task C
\task D
\task E
\task F
\task G
`.

Comment: @Zarko: Doesn't `tasks` number the itemzs row wise instead of columnwise?

Comment: `\raggedcolumns
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}` should work. See also: [Enumerate in multicols how to move the last element upwards](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116577/134144)

Comment: @leandriis, it might be, However OP doesn't provide any information about her/his document, so use of tasks is legitimate proposition :-). Of course it can be solved by `enumerate`. You can provide answer using it.

Comment: \raggedcolumns works!