# Multiple columns enumeration with automatically determined column numbers

Tags: enumerate, multicolumn

From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89611/8956), I have known how to write multiple columns enumeration.

But is it possible to automatically determine column numbers according to the maximal widths of all items, rather than manually specify the column number?

Comment: Not out of the box. You will need some programming behind the scenes in order to determine the number of items. If there are no special constructions like numbered equations, it might be done my gathering up the contents of the list, locally redefine `\item` to change a counter. *Run* the contents in a box (such that we can throw it away). Then the number of items is known and the list can be typeset as normal. You may find the `environ` and `etoolbox` packages helpful for this. Good luck.

Comment: your two linked questions so the two possible styles, but which do you want? numbering along the rows or down the coloumns?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Numbering along the rows is what I want. I have edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111173/specify-number-of-columns-in-brqalign/111174#111174) or actually the [original version](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51520/automatic-line-break-in-alignat/51543#51543) do this more or less