# Lists shaped like tables

Tags: tables, lists

As the title implies, I would like to find a way to write (ordered) lists in the shape of a table. This is particularly suitable for homeworks, for instance.

The solution I came with to use the multicol package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
[Solve the following equations:
]
\begin{enumerate}
\item Equation $1$
\item Equation $2$
\item Equation $3$
\item Equation $4$
\item Equation $5$
\item Equation $6$
\item Equation $7$
\item Equation $8$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that when the columns does not have the same number of items, the last has a big blank space.

Therefore, is there a solution to have a list shaped like a table? Of course, I could manually write a tabular and number the items myself but it is not very convenient when deleting/adding an item. An excellent answer would give the option to choose whether the list is enumerated vertically or horizontally.

For the management of possible non-equal columns/rows (as in my example), the rule should be: when the list is enumerate vertically, the blanks spaces are at the bottom of the right column; and a the right of the last row when the enumeration is horizontal.

Comment: *The problem is that when the columns does not have the same number of items, the last has a big blank space.* Then what is what you are looking for? How can that problem be solved if there are uneven number of items?

Comment: If you add `\raggedcolumns` after loading multicol the gap is at the bottom not between the items

Comment: You half imply you also want horizontal enumeration, for which see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111173/specify-number-of-columns-in-brqalign/111174#111174

Comment: Have you considered [this approach](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194577/22413) or [this other approach](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194450/22413)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `tasks` package, or use the `shortlst` package, that I have patched to have more flexibility.

I define a `tabenumerate` environment, which accepts two key=value arguments: `nc` is the number of columns (3 by default) and `il` is the baseline stretch (1.5 by default). The advantage with respect to other solutions is that if an item is wider than 1 column it `automatically` uses the next column. In addition, I define a `\paritem` command to insert a multiline item; it has an optional argument which is the number of columns used by this \paritem (1 by default), and a mandatory argument, the contents of the item.

Here is a demo of both solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tasks}

\settasks{counter-format=tsk.}
\usepackage{shortlst,setspace,xkeyval}%
\makeatletter
\newcounter{ncol}
\define@key{lex}{nc}[3]{\setcounter{ncol}{#1}}%% 3 columns by default
\define@key{lex}{il}[1.5]{\def\@intln{#1}}% interlining![1]
\newenvironment{tabenumerate}[1][]{%
\setkeys{lex}{nc,il,#1}
\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\mbox{(m)}}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%[1][3]
\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/\value{ncol}-\labelwidth-2\labelsep\relax}%
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\ensuremath{\arabic{enumi}.}}
\setstretch{\@intln}
\begin{shortenumerate}}%
{\end{shortenumerate}
 }%
 \newcommand\paritem[2][1]{\item \parbox[t]{#1\shortitemwidth}{\setstretch{1}#2\medskip}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\noindent Solve the following equations:
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task Equation $1$
\task Equation $2$
\task Equation $3$
\task Equation $4$ is a rather long equation
\task Equation $5$
\task Equation $6$
\task Equation $7$
\task Equation $8$
\end{tasks}
\bigskip

\noindent Solve the following equations:
\begin{tabenumerate}
  \item Equation $1$
\item Equation $2$
\item Equation $3$
\item Equation $4$ is a rather long equation
\item Equation $5$
\paritem[1] {Equation $6$ is another long equation}
\paritem[2] {Equation $7$ is a third long equation that stretches along two columns. }
\item Equation $8$

\end{tabenumerate}


\end{document} %
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It is very helpful. A last question (not sure it is worth an independant question): I use the tasks as a substitute of itemize when having rows of items is better than a columns. But how can I automatically use the style of a given depth of enumerate as a style for tasks?
(This follow-up question also gives me the opportunity to finally accept the answer :D)

Comment: I don't know, but if you know the style for enumerate at a given depth, you have tools to apply it. For instance, `\settasks{counter-format=(tsk[a]),label-width=1.5em}` sets the counter as (a), (b), (c), &c. with a width of 1.5em. It uses a system of  `key=value`. See § 4, pp.8-11 of the documentation for details.