# Print list in columns

Tags: tables, lists, enumerate, itemize, tabularx

I have a long list. I want to reduce the length this list uses. Can I somehow encapsulate all the entries in an environment which prints all the entries in a "3-column table", making me use more of the width of the page instead of having a long list?

I know I can use tabular but I need a solution which orders these entries automatically.

Comment: `\usepackage{multicol}`  and in the body `\begin{multicols}{3} your list \end{multicols}` should do

Comment: If you want an enumeration by rows, not by columns, you might consider the tasks or the shortlst package, as shown in the answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210032/lists-shaped-like-tables/210075#210075).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)}]
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The special **Alenanno** - Version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\listadd{\mywhitespacelist}{}%
\forcsvlist{\listadd\mywhitespacelist}{This,is,a,very,long,text,split,in,many,many,many,useless,separate,item,which,is,extended,just,because,Alenanno,wants,to,have,more,than,thirty,items,in,here,but,he,did,not,explain,why,this,is,the,case,so,who,cares?}



\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)}]
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
  \item \textbf{#1} 
}%
\dolistloop{\mywhitespacelist}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why stopping at 29? :P

Comment: @Alenanno: It's a prime number ... that's the only cause :-P

Comment: +1 although I can't get over the fact that it's not 30 items. :>

Comment: @Alenanno: I'll post an extra version to comfort you, ok?

Comment: @Bernard: No worries... I'll delete my comment above then