# put \item's in minipage

Tags: lists, minipage

Is it possible to have an `enumerate`- or `description`-like environment, with `\item` redefined in such a way so that each `\item` puts its content inside a `minipage`? Ideally, including the item number/title within the `minipage`?

Failing this, is the same possible with `\parbox{}` instead of minipage?

For background, I'd use this in conjunction with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89603/horizontal-enumeration-in-multiple-columns), so that I could have paragraph-like items that are stuffed into boxes that are say for example, `(1/3-epsilon)\textwidth` wide, and could then progress the items horizontally, 3 to a row. And then the next row would begin low enough to clear the tallest of the previous row's items.

Comment: You don't need minipages for that. You can use either the `shortlst` package  or the `tasks` package. See [myanswer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210032/lists-shaped-like-tables/210075#210075) to a similar question. Note shorlst, albeit on CTAN, is not part of TeX Live nor MiKTeX, for licensing reasons.

Comment: @Bernard Without getting into detail, I can't use something that's not part of the standard distributions. Also I'm looking for the functionality of your `\paritem`, but I need it to be used as `\item` is used, without requirement of braces.

Comment: `tasks` is in standard distributions, though.

Comment: I need its usage to be `\item This is my item`, not `\item{This is my item}`. It looks like `\paritem` has to work in the latter way, to pass its argument to the `\parbox`.

Comment: @alex.jordan: `tasks` has the same functionalities with the `\task*`  and `\task!` commands. See §3.2 of the documentation.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, the `tasks` package is great. Is it there an easy option to get `runin` style tasks? I don't see it in the documentation. But perhaps if `exsheets` is loaded too?

Comment: @alex.jordan: What do you call a *runin* style? Something like a runin list, i. e. not arranged in fixed width columns, but rather with items separated by a fixed horizontal length?

Comment: @Bernard I mean so that when an item moves on to a second line, the second line starts left flush with the item label.

Comment: @alex.jordan: Isn't that already the case without doing anything?

Comment: @Bernard No, unless I'm not explaining myself well. If you load `enumitem` and make an `enumerate` list with an item that extends to a second line, the option `itemindent=1.2em` simulates what I mean (but only for single digit enumerated items).

Comment: @alex.jordan: I've got it! I'll see if this is possible with `tasks`.

Comment: @cgnieder, how a question from 2015 can be duplicate to question from 2019?

Comment: @Zarko It's the same question and the other one has answers. The time of writing is not relevant for that. Only the question itself