# Horizontal list of equations with automatic column span

Tags: tables, equations, lists

I am looking for an environment to enumerate equations in a horizontal list with respect to their length such that they can spread into columns next to them:

---

[image: Example]

---

You can see that the integrals are short enough such that they fit in well. The fraction in (e) is so long that it spreads into the column where (c) is. What environment is most suitable for that?

Comment: You can use  either the `shortlst` or the `tasks` package. For an example of both, you can look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210032/lists-shaped-like-tables/210075#210075).

Comment: @Bernard `shortlst` seems to be what I want however it is not available via Miktex for some reasons.

Comment: Yes I know: it is neither in MiKTeX, nor in TeX Live, for licensing reasons, but you'll find it on CTAN. I once patched it to have the possibility to choose the number of columns. You have to install it by yourself in a TeXMF local root (which isn't very hard) and refresh the FNDB, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{shortlst,amsmath}       
\begin{document}

\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{.3\linewidth}
\begin{shortenumerate}
    \item $\displaystyle a_n  = \frac{4n^3 - (-1)^nn^2}{5n + 2n^3}$
    \item $\displaystyle b_n  = \frac{(n^3 - 5n)^4 - n^{12}}{n^{11}}$
    \item $\displaystyle c_n  = \frac{n^{n + 1}}{n!}$
    \item $\displaystyle e_n  = \frac{2^{(n^3)}}{n!5^{(n^2)} - n^n}$
    \item $\displaystyle f_n  = \sqrt{n + \sqrt{2n}} - \sqrt{n + \sqrt{2n}}x$
\end{shortenumerate}

\end{document}
```

The `shortlst` can be found [here](http://www.biwako.shiga-u.ac.jp/sensei/kumazawa/tex/shortlst.sty) and you can read the documentation also [here](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/table/shortlst.pdf). The package is neither in MiKTeX, nor in TeX Live, as pointed out by @Bernard for licensing reasons.

To set the maximum length of each item, you can say something like `\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{.3\linewidth}` to allow the items to overlap as in 3 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

[image: output]May be like this

```
\begin{align*}
(a)~~ a_n & = \frac{4n^3 - (-1)^nn^2}{5n + 2n^3} & (b)~~ b_n & = \frac{(n^3 - 5n)^4 - n^{12}}{n^{11}} & (c)~~ c_n & = \frac{n^{n + 1}}{n!} \\
(d)~~ e_n & = \frac{2^{(n^3)}}{n!5^{(n^2)} - n^n}   & (e)~~ f_n & = \sqrt{n + \sqrt{2n}} - \sqrt{n + \sqrt{2n}}x
\end{align*}
```

Comment: There is no enumeration.

Comment: thanks for pointing that. I just edited the answer. But there must be a nice way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution with `shortlst` patched so that you can choose the number of columns (default=3), line stretch (in case lines would overlap) and `\laaabelsep`, the distance between label and item body, through $3$ keys: `nc, il` and `ls`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{shortlst, setspace, amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{shortenumerate}{\renewcommand\labelenumi{(\alph{enumi})}
\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\mbox{(m)}}}


\makeatletter
\newcounter{ncol}
\define@key{lex}{nc}[3]{\setcounter{ncol}{#1}}%% 3 columns by default
\define@key{lex}{il}[1.5]{\def\@intln{#1}}% interlining![1]
\define@key{lex}{ls}[0.6em]{\setlength{\labelsep}{#1}}%%distance between label and item body
\newenvironment{tabenumerate}[1][]{%\setlength\labelsep{0.6em}
\setkeys{lex}{nc,il,ls, #1}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%[1][3]
\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/\value{ncol}-\labelwidth-2\labelsep\relax}%
\setstretch{\@intln}
\begin{shortenumerate}\everymath{\displaystyle}}%
{\end{shortenumerate}
 }%
 \newcommand\paritem[2][1]{\item \parbox[t]{#1\shortitemwidth}{\setstretch{1}#2\medskip}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{tabenumerate}[nc=3, il =2.5, ls =1em]
\item $ a_n = \frac{4n^3 - (-1)^nn^2}{5n + 2n^3}$
\item $ b_n = \frac{(n^3 - 5n)^4 - n^{12}}{n^{11}}$
\item $ c_n = \frac{n^{n + 1}}{n!}$
\item $ e_n = \frac{2^{(n^3)}}{n!5^{(n^2)} - n^n}$
\item $ f_n = \sqrt{n + \sqrt{2n}} - \sqrt{n + \sqrt{2n}}x$
\end{tabenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]